# Custom ValidationAttribute not displaying error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I wrote a custom ValidationAttribute to check if Email already exists in Db. However the error message is not displayed, and the validation occurs after I submit the form. The HTML contains the reference to the javascript files to display this messages but still no result. Nevertheless the other attributes work fine and their respective message is displayed.

```
public class NoDuplicateEmail : ValidationAttribute
{



     protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
          var context = new MhotivoContext();

         var email = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperties(
             ).FirstOrDefault(prop => IsDefined(prop, typeof(NoDuplicateEmail)));

         var emailValue = (string)email.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

         if(context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == emailValue)!=null)
             return new ValidationResult("Email is in use!");

         return ValidationResult.Success;

     } 

}
```

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [NoDuplicateEmail]
```

Comment: Not really clear what your trying to do with the `var email = ...` line? The `object value` contains the value of the property.

Comment: 1 - To validate on client, you have to create a custom javascript function. 2 - You need to call the database in order to validate the form, so you can't validate without an ajax call

Comment: @FabioLuz, You do not need a custom  javascript function. This is all built in to MVC (using the `[Remote]` attribute which internally makes an ajax call in conjunction with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`)

Comment: yeah, but remote makes an ajax call. I mean, to validate without calling the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `object value` parameter of the `IsValid` method contains the value of your email property so you `var email` and `var emailValue` lines of code are unnecessary. You code should be

```
public class NoDuplicateEmail : ValidationAttribute
{
  private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "Email {0} is in use!"
  public NoDuplicateEmail() : : base(_DefaultErrorMessage)
  {
  }

  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    var context = new MhotivoContext();
    if (value != null)
    {
      var email = (string)value;
      if(context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == emailValue) != null)
      {
        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(email));
      }
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

However you should NOT be accessing database resources in a validation attribute (that is not its responsibility and you code is impossible to unit test). You should be using the `[Remote]` attribute for client side validation and calling a service for server side validation.

Instead create a service method that returns a value indicating its valid (or add a private method in your controller

```
private bool isEmailInUse(string email)
{
  return context.Users.Any(x => x.Email == email)
}
```

and an `ActionResult` for client side validation

```
public JsonResult IsUniqueEmail(string email) // the parameter name must match the property name
{
  bool isInUse = isEmailInUse(email);
  return Json(!isInUse, JsonRequestBehavior);
}
```

And then apply the `RemoteAttribute` to your property

```
[Remote("IsUniqueEmail", yourControllerName, ErrorMessage = "The email is already in use")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

And finally, in the POST method (in case of a malicious user, or javascript has been disabled)

```
public ActionResult YourMethod (YourModel model)
{
  if (isEmailInUse(model.Email)
  {
    // add a ModelState error and return the view
  } 
}
```

or just catch the exception when you save (assuming the data base field has a unique constraint)